# ¿Can some one determine a full ETH public adress by just knowing the first 5 and last 4 digits of the public adress?

Tags: metamask

I'm just curious to know if addresses are determined by a pattern that only by knowing the first 5 and last 4 digits of and addresses you can complete the full missing address

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The address is 40 characters long, so knowing 9 digits, still leaves 31 unknown chars, which can be anything from 0 to F.

To answer your question, using the given chars there are 16^31 addresses deductable.